# MEAN stack application design

Tags: node.js, mongodb, angular, express, mean-stack

Looking for some insight/advice.

I'm creating an app where I want to expose an API that will be used by 3rd parties as well as my own web and mobile apps. Looking at the MEAN stack to do this. My thinking is that I should create 2 apps:

1. Express-based API app that talks to the MongoDB. No UI, just RESTful endpoints.
2. Angular-based web app with the UI. Does this app require Express? This app will hit the API endpoints to get/put data to the backend. Can Angular run on its own or does it need Express/Node. My thoughts were for Angular to handle the UI page routing and Express to handle the API routes.

Also, in the mix, is an iOS mobile app and Android app. These will also hit the API for data.

My background is heavy Java/Spring/Hibernate/Spring Boot and .Net. So, explaining MEAN stack as it relates to Java technology/frameworks would help!

Comment: Angular is (mostly) a front-end framework while Express is back-end. They don't "require" each other. Also, StackOverflow is about asking programming-related questions, you just ask us to explain the "MEAN stack", you can find many resourced about it online.

Comment: Trying to discern a question here. But for *"I want to expose an API that will be used by 3rd parties as well as my own "*. Then the answer is Angular has nothing to do with creating API's like you are talking about. Other tools for that. Asking for recommendations and opinions is off-topic, since nothing anyone tells you in this regard is **the** answer. Which is the point of this site.

Comment: More of a "best practices" question here. I have stood up an api application using mongodb and node with express. That's fine and works. I'm creating the web application with Angular. Is is best to make calls to the api application straight from Angular or should I add Express to the web app and make the api calls from the Express routes?

Comment: I am not sure about my answer, but here is my opinion. You can have two different hosting plans. First host your server side with database like node using express and mongodb. On the second hosting server you just put your angular code. There is no need of express. Every thing can be handled by angular. In angular service when you get or post data from/to node server, you should feed your node server url to the apropriate methods of http class's instance. Sorry, If I am wrong.